# Looking for a way to create a video or animated image of a series of segmented lines with cells in ImageJ

Tags: imaging, imagej

I considered asking this on software recs, but felt that the biology community would know better if ImageJ was capable of doing something this way, so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to do a project with ImageJ to model the movement of the flagellum of a Euglena cell. I have an MVI video file of a Euglena cell whipping its flagellum and I converted it into a series of TIFs. Then, I used the segmented line tool to draw over the flagellum so that each image has a "skeletal" line over the flagellum. What I want to do now is put the images together to construct a moving image that would act as a simplified model for the original video, but I don't want the background of the cell to be visible - just the skeletal lines. I want to fix one end of the line on a graph as the origin and be able to play the series of images back-to-back so the viewer will be able to focus solely on the movement of the line to more clearly visualize the cell's movement. It should look something like this:

https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/08/13/animating-double-pendulum/

I've considered using MATLAB, but I don't know if it can actually do it under the conditions I've laid out. I hope what I said makes sense because its a little difficult to put into words. Is there a way to do this in ImageJ or MATLAB, or do I need a different program entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're better off asking in a software forum as this isn't really a question about biology.

Comment: Or as a more specific alternative to @Armand suggestion, SE Bioinformatics, where people may be more familiar with the software.

Comment: Thank you. I was going back-and-forth with whether to post here or software recs, but I didn't think they'd know much about ImageJ. I've asked a similar question like this before and the recommendations I got there weren't really suitable for data analysis so I thought an answer was best from people who work in STEM. I didn't know there was an SE Bioinformatics so I'll try there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about biology as defined in the [help]. As suggested by @David it might be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE], but please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/), instead request migration by flagging your post for moderator intervention and explaining what you want and why.